# Как в js увеличить точность при вычислении чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в js повысить точность вычисления для чисел с плавающей точкой. Например, мне нужно, чтобы точность была до 100-го знака после запятой, можно ли этого добиться?

Comment: нет нельзя. только пользоваться специализированными библиотеками.

Comment: Что насчет алгоритмов длинной арифметики?

Comment: `BigDecimal` или `BigNumber`, но это сторонние библиотеки

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/